# How to solve Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross origin frame error in wordpress?

Tags: plugins, jquery, javascript, iframe

I am working on a WordPress website in which there are a lot of wordpress plugins installed.

The plugins installed on the wordpress website has the following options:

[image]

When I click on View details option, I am getting the blank screen as shown below in an image but when I open in a new window or tab, it works.

On checking console, I am getting the following error **(when clicking on View Details fails to open on the same page):**

```
Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame.
  at Contents
  at Function.map
  at a.fn.init.n.fn.(anonymous function) [as contents]
  and many other places.
```

[image]

**Problem Statement**:

I am wondering which file I need to modify in wordpress in order to solve this error. This error seems to exist in every wordpress plugins. It works in a new tab or window but fails to work in the same page.

At this moment, **I only have the wordpress admin access**. I am wondering where I need to go in wordpress in order to resolve this issue. **Do I need server access as well** in order to make modifications in the files ?

Comment: Could you explain if this a local staging/test server or live production server? And which kind of server? For example OS Ubuntu Apache server etc....

Comment: PS, I think something is wrong with your server and of course, you would need access to that server to solve the problem. I personally think that you would need to contact your web hosting provider if it's a live production server.

Comment: @RemziCavdar Its a test server but the problem exists in production server as well. Its Ubuntu.

Comment: @RemziCavdar I do have the access for server now. On running `lsb_release -a`, it has returned 

`No LSB modules are available.
 Distributor ID: Ubuntu
 Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
 Release:        16.04
 Codename:       xenial`

Comment: it's better to contact your hosting provider because in a default setup this would not occur.

Comment: I really would like to help you further, only the thing is I don't know your WP installation and what you did with your wp-config.php file. For example, did you do your salt settings with this: https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/  and have you enable debugging? define( 'WP_DEBUG', true ); see: https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress

Comment: Therefore I unable to provide you with a clear-cut answer, maybe if you provide us with more information or explain us how you installed WordPress on the server.

Comment: @RemziCavdar Hi Remzi, do you want me to check this file wp-config.php ? Because its not setup by me. In which file I need to check whether I have enable debugging  or not `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` ?

Comment: Yes wp-config.php debugging is enabled when you do define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );  My question I more like, is this the first time you have dealt with a WordPress install and what kind of configurations did you do?

Comment: Your question doesn't helps us, it's too vague and broad. Try to explain us what you did, how you installed WordPress and if you edited wp-config.php file. This file is more like a configuration settings file for WordPress

Comment: And could you disable all you plugins, check your install again and than enable them one after one and check theme one by one.

Comment: @RemziCavdar I didn't do the wordpress configuration on my own. The website is already built long time ago and someone has asked me 
to fix this bug.

Comment: @RemziCavdar I didn't install wordpress, someone else did it and asked me to fix the bug but I can definitely ask.

Comment: @RemziCavdar I deactivated plugin one-by-one and then I clicked on the view details button for the deactivated plugin and the plugin which is 
not deactivated (for both of them). I found the bug still exists. Now, going to check themes

Comment: @RemziCavdar But If you can send me some questions which can solve this issue. I can definitely the developer who built it. Let me know.

Comment: @RemziCavdar Let me know if you any have questions so that I can ask the developer to look into it.

Comment: The problem is, I really don't know. Because this normally would not happen. Maybe if you ask your developer to install WordPress again (an empty default WP setup) and then install the theme and plugins one by one and see what happens. You could also ask the dev of the server is on a proxy or something.

Comment: Also the problem is that you're not technical, you didn't properly answered my first question. The server you use, for example there are Apache, nginx, Mircosoft iis and etca...

Comment: Therefore we're unable to troubleshoot your issue, it could be a lot of different things, wrong server configuration, wrong WP setup, something with your theme or one of your plugins. Or your reverse proxy (if you use this) and in complex situations your load balancer / CDN like Clourdflare. You don't give use much information.

Comment: Ask your developer to look at this page and let him reply. This is a developer website for developers looking for answers to their issues. If you don't have some basic understanding then it's really pointless, because you wouldn't understand our questions to help fix your problem.

Comment: @RemziCavdar You could also ask the dev of the server is on a proxy or something -> `Its on ubuntu server`.

Comment: @RemziCavdar Just to let you know, I am also a developer but I didn't setup anything for this website. I was asked to solve this problem.

Comment: I'm not going to answer again, we're circling in circles here. You already said that it's running Ubuntu, but this is not what I asked. Ubuntu is the operating system (Linux distribution) I asked which server software you were running. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_server  But I assume you are running Apache start a topic on https://serverfault.com (also part of stackexchange network) I don't think this has anything to do with WordPress. You need to fix your server and / or .htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be from video iframe. Which can be in widget or anywhere you used. Did you added any video iframe from any channel which has any privacy or restriction.
If it's for particular plugin use case then please take a look around where you used or check plugin code or plugin issues if it has any issue then apply patch for that ?

Comment: He/she is clearly stating that this happens on the general plugins overview in WP admin. A widget shouldn't affect this area, it theoretically could but then it's a bad plugin/widget, to begin with. The only thing he/she could do is disable all the plugins, check if this issue still persists and activate the plugin's one by one and checking after activating a plugin. I think the server/.htaccess is not configured correctly, because this doesn't happen on a default setup/installation of WordPress. Or a combination of bad server config, bad plugin and/or theme.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't help us much, but I will try to answer your question.

You will need the following:

- FTP/SFTP/file access to your web server
- Basic understanding of a default setup of WordPress

### Web server

In the comments I try to troubleshoot the issue with you, you couldn't answer all my questions. I assume your web server is [Apache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server) and therefore I ask you to edit your question/post to include the [.htaccess](https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess) file on your server. (Just post the contents)

**Example default WordPress .htaccess file**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

### WordPress

I also advise disabling all your plugins and check if the issue still persists and activate plugins one by one and to check after each activation.

If you have disabled all your plugins and restored/fixed your .htaccess file, try to install and activate a different theme (preferably one of the default themes of WordPress https://wordpress.org/themes/twentyseventeen/)

### Enable debugging

Enable debugging in WordPress by editing the `wp-config.php` file located in the root install of WordPress. Edit `wp-config.php` and set `WP_DEBUG` to true:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
```

See for more documentation: https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress

I think the server/.htaccess is not configured correctly, because this doesn't happen on a default setup/installation of WordPress. Or a combination of bad server config, bad plugin and/or theme.